# sql query problem, manipulate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have stored proc that will tell us if there is any new checks to be printed. Now I have to manipulate the data in database table in order to get at least one check to be printed. I didn't write this query. I tried but I didn't get at least one check to be printed. Can anyone help me. HERE IS THE STORED PROC

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [proc_1250_SELCashiersChecksForPrint] AS

SELECT t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.BatchNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.SerialNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckRTN, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.CheckAccountNbr, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Amount, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Payee, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Address, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.City, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.State, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Zip, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimId, t_DATA_Reclamation.NoticeDate, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.FirstName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.MiddleName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.LastName, 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimTotal, 
    t_PCD_Claimant.Name AS Agency, 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.IDENTITYCOL
FROM t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued INNER JOIN
    t_DATA_Reclamation ON 
    t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr = t_DATA_Reclamation.ControlNbr
     INNER JOIN
    t_PCD_Claimant ON 
    t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimantCode = t_PCD_Claimant.ClaimantCode
WHERE (t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.SerialNbr IS NULL) AND 
    (t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.DateIssued IS NULL)
ORDER BY t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.Audit_DateAdded ASC, 
 t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr ASC

GO
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the tables have data, this will update the first row.

```
UPDATE TOP(1) t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued
   SET SerialMbr = NULL,
       DataIssued = NULL
  FROM t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued 
 INNER JOIN t_DATA_Reclamation 
    ON t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued.ControlNbr = t_DATA_Reclamation.ControlNbr 
 INNER JOIN t_PCD_Claimant 
    ON t_DATA_Reclamation.ClaimantCode = t_PCD_Claimant.ClaimantCode
```

Comment: I DON'T WANT TO CHANGE THE PROC. i WANT TO MANIPULATE TABLES DATA (LIKE ADDING EXTRA DATA) IN ORDER TO GET ATLEAST ONE CHECK TO BE PRINTED. SO CAN YOU TELL ME WHICH TABLE OR COLUMN DATA DO I NEED TO CHANGE IN ORDER TO GET ATLEAST ONE CHECK TO BE PRINTED.

Comment: The above SQL will manipulate the data so the stored proc will print one cheque.

Comment: where do i need to execute this query? i mean in which table? i opened t_DATA_CashiersChecksIssued table in sql enterprise manager and tried to execute that one. But it didn't.

Comment: You'll need to execute it in SQL Server Management Studio from a Query window (New Query button top left hand corner).